# How do I choose between `std::cout` and `std::wcout` according to the defined string type?

Tags: c++, string, compile-time, c++17

I defined my own string type in the code.

```
typedef wchar_t CharType;
typedef std::basic_string<CharType> StringType;
```

I have a static class (it won't have an instance) which will print string messages on the screen. I decided to put a `COUT` static member which will refer to `std::cout` or `std::wcout` according to the string type I defined.

Header:

```
#include <ostream>

class MyTestClass
{
    public:
        // ...
        static std::basic_ostream<CharType> & COUT;
        // ...
}
```

CPP:

```
std::basic_ostream<CharType> & MyTestClass::COUT = /* How do I initialize this? */;
```

Is there a way of initializing this static member `COUT`?

Comment: isn't your `StringType` equal to `std::wstring`?

Comment: You know, you could also just overload the `<<` operator instead of wrapping `std::cout`...

Comment: @appleapple @Ron The char type I defined is changable during development. There are a lot of other definitions in my code that are defined according to this char type at compile time. So, `CharType` is not always `wchar_t`, therefore it is not possible to simply assign `std::wcout` to `COUT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an option in C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
auto &get_cout() {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, char>){
        return std::cout;
    }else{
        return std::wcout;
    }
}

int main() {
    {
        using CharType = char;
        std::basic_ostream<CharType> & MyTestClass_COUT = get_cout<CharType>();
        MyTestClass_COUT << "Hello";
    }
    {
        using CharType = wchar_t;
        std::basic_ostream<CharType> & MyTestClass_COUT = get_cout<CharType>();
        MyTestClass_COUT << L"World";
    }
}
```

If you don't have C++17 you can replace `if constexpr` with a trait-based solution.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12e9890a67fbcb2d).

Comment: I don't believe this would work with tag dispatching, as the return type of `get_cout` would be inconsistent. The question is tagged C++17 though, so this is fine.

Comment: @zennehoy Why would the return types need to be consistent? Your solution with a getter function instead of a `static constexpr` member would work just fine.

Comment: Your `get_cout` function has an `auto &` return type that is resolved as either `std::ostream` or `std::wostream`, based on which return statement is chosen. This works in C++17 with the `if constexpr`, but you could not have two such incompatible return statements in C++14 or before.

Comment: @zennehoy Hmm, [works fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/019573b91c4615c5) in C++11. It probably compiles in C++98 too, but coliru's standard library doesn't support it anymore.

Comment: Sure, but that's not tag dispatching, that's a traits-based solution. All I'm getting at is that in C++14 and before, you cannot return two different types from the same function depending on an if within that function (as your `get_cout` is doing).

Comment: @zennehoy You are right, I used the wrong term. Fixed, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Old fashioned trait style solution:

```
template<class T>
struct cout_trait {};

template<>
struct cout_trait<char> {
    using type = decltype(std::cout);
    static constexpr type& cout = std::cout;
    static constexpr type& cerr = std::cerr;
    static constexpr type& clog = std::clog;
};
template<>
struct cout_trait<wchar_t> {
    using type = decltype(std::wcout);
    static constexpr type& cout = std::wcout;
    static constexpr type& cerr = std::wcerr;
    static constexpr type& clog = std::wclog
};
```

Usage:

```
auto& cout = cout_trait<char>::cout;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a specialized class to do the selection for you:

```
template <typename T_Char>
struct StreamSelector;

template <>
struct StreamSelector<char> {
    static constexpr std::ostream &stream = std::cout;
};

template <>
struct StreamSelector<wchar_t> {
    static constexpr std::wostream &stream = std::wcout;
};

std::basic_ostream<CharType> &COUT = StreamSelector<CharType>::stream;
```

This works starting with C++11, though it could be modified slightly to work before that.